# How I can resize and draw image instantly in using java?

Tags: java, performance, swing, image-resizing

I'm using getScaledInstance() method of BufferedImage and repaint() method of JLayeredPane to resize and draw image on the screen in real-time. But I've seen an article which says repaint() method is not appropriate since it doesn't refresh the layeredPane instantly. However there was no alternative way described.

I also built a remote app and it sends a message whenever pan gesture is detected. And when java program received a message, it calls the method I wrote.

Here's the code I'm using. What can I use instead of repaint() method?

```
public void resizeImage(float percentage) { 
    if (percentage > 0) {
        int newWidth = (int)(originalImage.getWidth() * (percentage / 100));
        int newHeight = (int)(originalImage.getHeight() * (percentage / 100));

        Image tmp = originalImage.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        imageForDisplay = dimg;
        layeredPane.repaint();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By immediately you mean synchronous?

Comment: repaint() will repaint the component "as soon as possible". Are you having concrete problems with your repaint?

Comment: getScaledInstance is pretty asynchronous, idea (starting with Graphics2D  g2d) from code posted is wrong

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I continuously call the method and it seems laggy and slow.

Comment: @BluesSolo I mean I have remote app and it sends messages to this program. Whenever message received the method I posted is called. I'm not a English speaker. So plz understand if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @mKorbel Where I can start from to do it in proper way?

Comment: This seems like a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It is far more likely that the lagginess is due to a) the fact that scaling an image isn't a cheap operation or b) the lag is induced by the remote connection. You should first figure out what it is (e.g. send commands directly from your java app to check if it still slow/laggy) and then update your question accordingly. Also, creating dimg/g2d isn't necessary, just do `imageForDisplay = tmp;` I think this is what @mKorbel meant.